# Exit Python cmd sub interpreter without exiting the script

Tags: python, python-2.7, cmd

I am writing a tool that utilizes the Python 2.7 cmd module and I wrote several sub interpreters and I am wondering how I can exit a sub interpreter without killing the Python script. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding this to the do_exit function

```
def do_exit(self, args):
    return -1
```